# When user types in & rest of string dissapears

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox

In a search text box when a user types in & the text after this is not passed to the function.
So if industry & test is typed in and submitted, only industry is passed to the function. How do i accept in the amp sound?

Text box:

```
 Search <input type="text" id="searchtxt" /><img class ="SearchNow"src="/Content/img/search1.png"/>
```

Jquery to call function:

```
 $(".SearchNow").click(function () {
        var selected = $('#searchtxt').val();
        if (selected != null) {
            if (selected != "") {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("search", "Products")?partnumber=' + selected;
            }
        }
    });
```

function where text is not all coming in:

```
 public ActionResult search(string partnumber)
    {


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapped it with:

```
encodeURIComponent(selected)
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be due to & being a querystring delimiter. You'll need to escape the text before you pass it to the url:

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("search", "Products")?partnumber=' + encodeURIComponent(selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to encode the user's input in a manner suitable for passing into a URL.

So, change `+ selected` to `+ encodeURI(selected)` and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` is a special character in the Url and marks the next paramteter to be passed. The first parameter is marked with an **?** and the following with **&**'s. So encode this **&** and it will be passed.

Answer (score 0):

The & character is used a special character to separate parameters.

The posted code redirects the page to http://tld.invalid/searchAction?partnumber=industry%20&%20test

which has two parameters:
partnumber="industry "
and
 test= ""

You need to encode the parameters to pass it to the server properly.

```
var selected = encodeURIComponent( $('#searchtxt').val() );
window.location = '@Url.Action("search", "Products")?partnumber=' + selected;
```

which should redirect the user to http://tld.invalid/searchAction?partnumber=industry%20%26%20test